# QDialog not displayed correctly when opening again

Tags: qt, qt5

I have this issue with Qt5. In my GUI, if I press a button to open another window, I have the following code:

```cpp
void Viewer::openWindow() {
  if (!m_window){
    m_window = new myWindow(this);
  }
  m_window->raise();
  m_window->show();
  return;
}
```

Where `myWindow` inherits from `QDialog`. This is in an existing codebase and I know that there are probably many pitfalls. e.g. if I set deleteOnClose I will have dangling pointers and so on ... all of this doesn't happen though and in principle it works. I also have a "Close" button which will call `reject()` which works fine.

The issue I'm having is when I press the "X" on that Dialog - the window will disappear just fine. Once I try to reopen it (i.e. calling `Viewer::openWindow()` again) it won't display its contents properly. I can resize the window and it will look fine. However, any change in the GUI (like selecting something from a dropdown menu will not work smoothly though) will somewhat lag behind. It somewhat seems like the window is not redrawing properly.

I don't have this issue when I close the window with the close button though - there I can reopen it just fine.

I also tried calling `repaint()` or `update()` on that Dialog, that didn't help.

And ideas?

Comment: When you click the X on the window it will be destroyed. Unless you prevent it from doing so and just hide the window.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not happening - because of multiple reasons: as far as I know, a QDialog will only do this if `WA_DeleteOnClose` is set (which I don't and it's not set by default). Also, the subsequent calls of `raise()` and `show()` don't segfault - the window is still there and "half" works.

Comment: To sort this out, it could help to expose a [mcve].